# Get MAX results of pm messages

Tags: php, max

I'm trying to get the last result of each conversation between two users with no prevail. I've looked at a few examples online such as

[[php Mysql Grouping and Ordering user messages together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408662/php-mysql-grouping-and-ordering-user-messages-together][1])

AND a more advanced query

[[GROUP BY messages MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348155/group-by-messages-mysql][1])

My database structure below.
My conversations rely on getting id's of both `message_creator` and `message_target` to link them into one chat.

```
message_id,
message_content,
message_target,
message_creator,
message_status, 
message_time
```

I need `message_status` to also select 1 AND 2 in the query so if a user has read the last message it still shows as last message in the conversation.

Here is the query I currently have.

```
$callmessage=" SELECT message_id,MAX(message_content) AS message_content ,message_target,message_status,message_creator,message_throughurl,MAX(message_time) AS message_time FROM messages WHERE message_target='$user1_id' OR message_creator='$user1_id' AND message_status=1 OR message_status=2 
    Group By 
    (if(message_creator > message_target,  message_creator,message_target))
     ,(if(message_creator > message_target,  message_target,message_creator)) 
    ORDER BY message_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the very last message between two users, then this should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE ( 
    (message_creator='$user1_id' AND message_target='$user2_id')
    OR 
    (message_creator='$user2_id' AND message_target='$user1_id')
)
AND message_status IN (1,2)
ORDER BY message_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm not using user2_id. Also you removed the group by messages out and that is the source of my problem. I need to get the last message_id of each group

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've worked it out and its working. This is what I've done with my query, just a few little bits to add.

```
$user1_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$callmessage="  SELECT * FROM messages WHERE message_id IN
    (SELECT MAX(message_id) AS message_id FROM
    (SELECT message_id, message_creator AS id_with
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_target = '$user1_id'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT message_id, message_target AS id_with
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_creator= '$user1_id') t
    GROUP BY id_with)";
```